# Vertical Scrolling On Unslider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Unslider](https://github.com/idiot/unslider) on a template I'm making. I'm using [j.Query.event.swipe](http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/) to give it touch/swipe support on mobile.

The problem is that on mobile, the slider isn't vertically touch responsive – you can't scroll up and down unless you're touching outside of the slider element. The left/right swiping works fine, you can swipe through the slides, you can't scroll up and down the page with your finger unless you're touching outside the slider itself.

I have a feeling it's a problem with the jQuery, but I can't figure out what it is. Here's my code on index.html at the bottom of :

```
<!-- Reference jQuery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <!-- Reference Javascript, minify for production -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.event.move.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.event.swipe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/unslider.js"></script>

    <!-- Unslider script -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var unslider = $('.slider').unslider();
            $('.unslider-arrow').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
                    unslider.data('unslider')['next']();  
                } else {
                    unslider.data('unslider')['prev']();  
                };
            });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer: https://github.com/idiot/unslider/pull/76

```
var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();
unslider.on('movestart', function(e) {
if((e.distX > e.distY && e.distX < -e.distY) || (e.distX < e.distY && e.distX > -e.distY)) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```